# Deleteing media files from cloudinary failing due to "cloudinary.uploader is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I am working on a web application with express and node.js. I am using cloudinary to upload media files. Uploading and accessing media is working fine. But I can't delete the images from cloudinary. This is the code I am using to delete:

```
for (let filename of req.body.deleteImages) {
    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename);
}
```

I tried console logging the cloudinary object and everything seems to be in order:

```
cloudinary: {
      config: [Function (anonymous)],
      utils: [Object],
      uploader: [Object],
      api: [Object],
      provisioning: [Object],
      PreloadedFile: [class PreloadedFile],
      Cache: [Object],
      url: [Function: url],
      image: [Function: image],
      video: [Function: video],
      source: [Function: source],
      picture: [Function: picture],
      cloudinary_js_config: [Function: cloudinary_js_config],
      CF_SHARED_CDN: 'd3jpl91pxevbkh.cloudfront.net',
      AKAMAI_SHARED_CDN: 'res.cloudinary.com',
      SHARED_CDN: 'res.cloudinary.com',
      BLANK: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
      search: [class Search]
    }
```

But I am getting `Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined` error when the function is called. I tried console logging `cloudinary.uploader` and I am getting `undefined`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you initializing the Cloudinary module?

Comment: Cloudinary module is initialised as an object in a separate file with the API key and secret passed in as options. The object itself is working fine because I am able to upload media files through the object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The issue was that I was not destructuring the cloudinary module when I was importing it. So the cloudinary variable I was trying to access was the entire module instead of the exported object that I needed to use. Thank you for taking the time to read my question.